# Spring boot OAuth2 - Insufficient Scope for this resource

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have an access token with the necessary scope. I also successful access the resource server. The error occur when the resource server try to fetch the user Principal from the Authorization server. I really hope i can get some hints or help about how i can solve this

- The access Token:

  {"access_token":"65ce0f1a-192f-4ad2-b7bb-cb9c7cbf0be9","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"f1e2a49d-5b24-4e9c-b9da-567eb47d6ab7","expires_in":149,"scope":"read write trust"}
- The resource server call:

  curl -H "Authorization:Bearer 65ce0f1a-192f-4ad2-b7bb-cb9c7cbf0be9" http://localhost:9001/resource/hello
- Resource server output after the call:

  2016-10-10 10:10:06.144  INFO 411 --- [nio-9001-exec-5] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: http://localhost:9000/auth/user

The endpoint (localhost:9000/auth/user) get executed but i always get the following response to my curl request:

```
{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":"Insufficient scope for this resource","scope":"read"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by removing the user info uri from the resource server properties. Since I use a jdbc token store, the resource server can verify the authenticity of the token from the database and not relying on the auth server anymore.

Comment: Where exactly resource server properties located ?